# Node app with different environments in jenkins

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, web-applications, environment

I'm working actually on a node web application for my master's degree project. I need to make it like a real project with different environments : Dev, Test and Prod in Jenkins

This is my docker ps :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhuZP.png)

And this is my Jenkinsfile :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQkuE.png)

Till now I work only in one environment and I do everything on it. I don't know how to do ?

Remarque : I didn't install Mocha and Katalon yet for test.

Thanks by advance.

Mahmoud

Answer (score 0):

- Create git branches for each environment.
- Define criteria for merging from one branch into the next.
- Create Jenkins pipelines to enforce this criteria.
- Restrict user access to certain branches.

This process acts as a barrier to stop developers from promoting buggy code straight to production.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply but I think more details should be very helpful.